App triggering a weird request to a server-actions.js.map
I have a Next.js app, everything works fine except when I check the Terminal, I keep seeing this call that is triggering a long error stack messages:
GET /_next/static/chunks/app/%5Blang%5D/%5B...slug%5D/server-actions.js.map 500 in 60ms

I am wondering:

Where does that call coming from?
Why is the middleware intercepting this request since it's supposed to ignore it:

export const config = {
  matcher: [
    /*
     * Match all paths except for:
     * 1. /api routes
     * 2. /_next (Next.js internals)
     * 3. /_static (inside /public)
     * 4. all root files inside /public (e.g. /favicon.ico)
     */
    '/((?!api/|_next/|_static/|_vercel|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)',
  ],
};

The file I am calling is located in:
src/app/[lang]/[...slug]/page.tsx

Anyone faced a similar issue and was able to fix that?
Thanks a lot for any kind of help to get rid of this error :)

Can you share your file structure?

Added to my post ;)

Are you by any chance using server actions in your page.tsx ?, can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

I removed all server actions but still having the same issue. Unfortunately it's quite a big project and it's hard to re-create a minimal reproducible example :(
